# C++ auto type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to do automatic type deduction but it should only work if the 
inputs are fields.

I have declared a function like this:

```
template<class C> C gettype();
```

And I use it like this:

```
template<class L, class R, int F = CField<L,R>::is>
struct AddType {
    typedef decltype (gettype<L>() + gettype<R>()) type;
};
```

but I get a plethora of errors:

1. that `getType` cannot be used as a parameter.
2. that the compiler expects a ';' at the call to decltype.
   and that I need type specifiers.

etc.

Am I missing a lib or am I thinking about this all wrong?

thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You may want to use `std::declval` rather then a homebrew solution.

Comment: The code compiles just fine to me (Im missing the CField parameter, but I took the liberty to remove it). Are you compiling for C++11? Sounds like you forgot to set the compiler to C++11 mode

Comment: thanks i'll try that.

Comment: @gdasamu that worked!! thanks much.